# JSF: fit width of richModal panel to width of content

Tags: jsf, richfaces, width, panel, modal-dialog

Have `rich:modalPanel` panel component:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="pnl" zindex="10000"  height="510" width="400" style="overflow: scroll"  onresize="return false;">
```

Content of this panel displayed in width not completely, so scroll id displayed.

How to fit to width to avoid horizontal scroll at all?

tried:

`style="overflow: auto"`    -didn't help
`style="overflow: visible"` -displayed not correctly, with transparent background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the attribute "autosized" to true and remove the "width" attribute. You also can remove the style attribute.

Hope it helps!

More info http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf